# Intergrating ASP.net feed into twitter

Tags: asp.net, twitter, rss, atom-feed

I have a ready RSS atom feed on my ASP.net site,but I want to publish it through twitter how? and what it's requirment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

- [**TwitterFeed**](http://twitterfeed.com/)